# ASP.NET - cannot create MVC controller with view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 to make a website for a school project, but when I try to choose the option to make a MVC controller along with views, using Entity Framework, I get this error every time (see "Error Message" image, since I cannot copy it). I've tried the solutions to many other related questions on this site, but nothing has changed. If anyone can suggest a solution, I'd really appreciate it!

[MVC Controller Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXGXJ.png)

[MVC Creation Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUF9a.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg6Yl.png)

Things I've tried:

I get the same problem for any project, even one downloaded for my professor's GitHub page (Scaffolding works for him), meaning this has nothing to do with my code.

Installed the latest `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` globally

Installed the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration` package

I have also tried repairing and uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio

Tried all solutions listed on [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139243/asp-net-core-scaffolding-does-not-work-in-vs-2017)

Comment: Try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139243/asp-net-core-scaffolding-does-not-work-in-vs-2017

Comment: Forgot to mention I've tried all of those already. Thanks anyways

Comment: Don't post images, copy the important text into your question. The scaffolder seems confused about your binding address, mixing IPv6 and IPv4 loopback addresses into one string, which doesn't make any sense. Check the project properties for the app url?