# I have a problem generating a controller with views in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2022 (which license will end in 2 days) to create a website for my school project.

I'm using the code-first method. Therefore I have already created my model classes and my context page.

Here is the code of each class:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string imageURL { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float price { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 5), Required]
    public float rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MakerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Maker? Maker { get; set; }
}

public class Maker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255)]
    public string Adresses { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public int Tel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Game>? Games { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `DbContext`:

```
public class GamesDbContext : DbContext
{
    public GamesDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

After all the above, I took the liberty to configure the connection string by taking it from a previous project that worked and changed only the database name to projectDB.

Once the migration and database update command finished, I checked whether the database was created successfully or not. And it has.

Finally, I wanted to create my controller and views by right clicking the controllers folder and choosing the "add controller" option. In which, I opted to create the controller with views using Entity Framework. Keep in mind that I have installed the following packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServe(v6.0.12)(tried installing v6.10.10 still the same error)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(v6.0.10)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(v6.0.10)
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design(v6.0.10)

Here is the options screen :

[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSzbC.png)

and here is the error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK3s3.png)

I have not faced this error before and would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this predicament.

PS: I already tried out the solutions in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139243/asp-net-core-scaffolding-does-not-work-in-vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the options screen it looks like you have chosen `SR.Models.GamesModels` for both model class and db context class. You should select your class `Game` for the model and `GamesDbContext` for the data context class in the options screen.

Comment: SR.Models.GameModels is just the folder that contains the classes. if you check again you would find that i chose the class "Game" for the model and The "GamesDbContext" for the Context class

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServe(v6.0.12) to be of a higher update than the others?
You could reinstall this package to the same version as the others OR
A tip would be if your Packages are acting up, make a Copy of your entire work. Then delete all your Dependency's reinstall them.

(just some extra)
your DBset seems to be missing Maker try to use this in dbcontext

```
public DbSet<Maker> Makers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. I have tried the solution that you have mentioned, but unfortunately it did fix my problem as the error still occurs. If you have another solution in mind, then I would really appreciate it if you could provide me with it.